# Where does the Chrome web store "Support" tab come from?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm creating a packaged Chrome app for the Chrome web store ... how do I enable a "Support" tab on my app page within the store?

[image]

I'm reading the [documentation on manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest), but I don't see any property that enables this support tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a global setting available in your Dashboard:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

Word of advice: *don't do it* and make some other support link available (which you can set in the item's edit page in the dashboard, and will show up on that tab). The support page function [will not notify you anyhow](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=295837) about new questions, and the team is [reluctant to even attempt to fix it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=295837#c12).