# How to get support tab for Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm not sure if this is the correct exchange for this questions as I don't think it is explicitly programming related, but I can't think of a better place to ask the question.

I keep seeing this tab for chrome extensions that allows users to ask questions, suggest things or submit problems:

[image]

I haven't been able to find anything in the developer dashboard or in documentation about this tab.  I know that I can get a support tab with a link by adding a url to the support link field in the project settings, but I can't figure out how to get the functionality shown here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does the Chrome web store "Support" tab come from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491901/where-does-the-chrome-web-store-support-tab-come-from)

Comment: While that question is a very similar to mine, it is referring to a Chrome App, not an extension, and the answer did not help me.

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

Click in the link:

- Edit your User Feedback preferences: User Feedback is disabled

And then enable it.

It's the same answer for [Where does the Chrome web store "Support" tab come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491901/where-does-the-chrome-web-store-support-tab-come-from), it works for Apps and extensions.

Comment: Also, can I remove some support messages from the chrome developer dashboard?
Thank you!